# Remove text before and after a string but with limiters

Tags: string, text, awk, sed

I was using sed to remove lines with specific words:

```
string=${line##* }
sed "/$string/d" $dhcp
```

The inconvenience of this is that there are parts of the text that I can not safely remove.

The ideal would look something like this:

example:
input:

```
 config host
        mac '00:a0:00:00:00:00'
        option name 'laptop1'
        option dns '1'

config host
        option mac '00:a0:00:00:00:00'
        option name 'string'
        option dns '1'

 config host
        option name 'laptop3'
        mac '00:a0:00:00:00:00'
        option dns '1'
```

Output

```
config host
        option mac '00:a0:00:00:00:00'
        option name 'laptop1'
        option dns '1'

 config host
        option name 'laptop3'
        mac '00:a0:00:00:00:00'
        option dns '1'
```

What would be the best method for this?

grateful for the attention

Comment: I chose based on portability but it is even difficult to say which really is the best answer. Thank you all! / awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '!/'$string'/' file

Comment: Dont let a shell variable (especially an unquoted one) expand to become part of the body of a shell script. See http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24. The most common way to use the value of a shell variable inside that awk script would be `awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' -v str="$string" '$0!~str' file`.

Comment: Thanks, this worked very well in variables with more words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sed is for doing `s/old/new/` on individual input lines **that is all**. Although it has a million arcane combinations of characters to do other things, all of those became obsolete in the mid 1980s when awk was invented and unless they're masochists people only use them today for the mental exercise, not for real code.

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '!/string/' file
 config host
        mac '00:a0:00:00:00:00'
        option name 'laptop1'
        option dns '1'

 config host
        option name 'laptop3'
        mac '00:a0:00:00:00:00'
        option dns '1'
```

.

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '!/laptop1/' file
config host
        option mac '00:a0:00:00:00:00'
        option name 'string'
        option dns '1'

 config host
        option name 'laptop3'
        mac '00:a0:00:00:00:00'
        option dns '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat $dhcp | tr '\n' '\r' | sed -e "s/\r\r.*'string'.*\r\r/\r\r/" | tr '\r' '\n'
```

Explaining:

1. `tr '\n' '\r'`:
   Replace `\n` by `\r`, to allow `sed` to work with "break lines".
2. `sed -e "s/\r\r.*'string'.*\r\r/\r\r/"`:
   Replace by empty string the occurence `'string'` and its sibling characters until find double break lines.
3. `tr '\r' '\n'`:
   Change back `\r` by `\n`

Answer (score 0):

Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk '/config host/{if(val){print val};non_flag=val=""} /option name \047string\047/{non_flag=1;val=""}  !non_flag && NF{val=val?val ORS $0:$0} END{if(val){print val}}'  Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk '
/config host/{
  if(val){
     print val};
  non_flag=val=""
}
/option name \047string\047/{
  non_flag=1;
  val=""
}
!non_flag && NF{
  val=val?val ORS $0:$0
}
END{
  if(val){
    print val}
}'   Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code too now.

```
awk '
/config host/{                ##Searching for text config host in a line if it is there then do following.
  if(val){                    ##If variable val is NOT NULL then do following.
     print val};              ##printing the value of variable val here.
  non_flag=val=""             ##Nullifying the variables non_flag and val here.
}
/option name \047string\047/{ ##Searching for string option name 'string' here if it is found then do following.
  non_flag=1;                 ##Setting up the value of variable non_flag as 1 here.
  val=""                      ##Nullifying the variable named val here.
}
!non_flag && NF{              ##Checking conditions if variable non_flag is NULL and line is NOT a empty line then do following.
  val=val?val ORS $0:$0       ##Create variable named val and each time cursor comes here concatenate its value with its own value.
}
END{                          ##Starting END section of awk code here.
  if(val){                    ##Checking if variable val is NOT NULL then do following,
    print val}                ##Printing variable val value here.
}' Input_file                 ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

***NOTE:*** In case you Input_file is a shell variable which looks like from your post then change from `Input_file` to `"$dhcp"`.

Answer (score 0):

**awk **

```
    set str1=laptop1 ; //set string for removed section 

    awk -v RS="config host" -v a=$str '($0!~a)&&(NR>1) {printf "%s", RS $0 }' file
```

`1)` `RS="config host"` - set record separator to wanted string .

`2)` `-v str1=$str1` get argument (string to search in recorded string, in our case `$str1=laptop1`).

`3)` `($0!~str1)&&(NR>1)` - records that doesn't contain the `$str` string.

`4)` `{printf "%s",RS $0 }` - print the record separator and recorded string

Comment: You should mention that will only work with GNU awk due to multi-char RS.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this gnu sed

```
sed '/./!d;:A;$bB;N;/\n$/!bA;:B;/string/d' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/config host/{:a;N;/^\s*$/M!ba;/string/d}' file
```

Gather up lines beginning with `config host` to an empty line. If the lines contains `string` delete those lines otherwise print them.